# CRLF into java string

Tags: java, string

I've coded a string in Java where I inserted a LF (linefeed) at the end like this:

```
String str = "......\n";
```

Now I need to need [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) made of a [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and a [Line Feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm), a CRLF. In hex that is `0D 0A` instead of `0A`. Is there a way to insert this into my string?

Answer (score 65):

Use `\r\n`:

```
String str = "......\r\n";
```

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6):

```
\n    /* \u000a: linefeed LF */
\r    /* \u000d: carriage return CR */
```

Comment: how have you determined it to not be working correctly? because this is definitely the correct way to insert a CR LF into the string

Comment: @ClaudioPomo `echo -e -n "foo\r\n" | xxd` produces `666f 6f0d 0a`, as it should. `"...\r\n"` is the way to produce `0x0d 0x0a`. Of course, if you look at the source code, you'll get `666f 6f5c 725c 6e`.

Comment: @ClaudioPomo - please write an SSCE for this, because (frankly) what you are reporting is hard to believe.

Comment: Correct Answer. You may find it useful to make a variable or constant for the end-of-line value: `final String eol = "\r\n" ;`   and then do `String s = "yourTextHere" + eol ;`

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use constant strings.  I've taken this from my own ASCII class which defines all 33 non printable codes as their ASCII name, e.g.

```
public final static char CR  = (char) 0x0D;
public final static char LF  = (char) 0x0A; 

public final static String CRLF  = "" + CR + LF;     // "" forces conversion to string

String twoLines = "Line1" + CRLF + "Line2";   // 12 characters
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset the system property to "\r\n":

```
System.setProperty("line.separator","\r\n");
```

Regards

Comment: You should avoid messing with system properties. Also, this is not a useful and complete answer to the question.